# opencv light issue while performing face recognition

Tags: ios, iphone, opencv, face-recognition, lbph-algorithm

I am currently working on Face recognition using opencv with LBPH algorithm. But I am getting issue that I have trained many faces at evening of different person and it was working at that time, but the next day I am not getting the same result.

What are the best possible ways to handle this issue?

I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: i am also facing same issue if you getting any solution pls tell me

Comment: Have you tried training your datasets in different color spaces which are less susceptible to changes in light for eg. HSV, Lab, Luv?

Comment: No, I haven't tried yet. Actually I am new in opencv.

Comment: Can you please give me reference link for it?

Comment: Here you go, [this is a nice tutorial](https://www.learnopencv.com/color-spaces-in-opencv-cpp-python/)

Answer (score 0):

In order to increase your Face Recognition System accuracy you should train your network on images of the different individuals photographed in different ambients, at different time during the day, from different distances, in different poses and with different illumination setups.

Once you have acquired this dataset, retrain your network on it and you should see that the predicition confidence increases and false positive decrease accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But i am getting issue is that I have trained my face 2 days ago and now i am getting unexpected results.

Comment: i have trained 4-5 persons with 20 images each.

Comment: So it is really weird you're getting unexpected results. False positive occurs when the number of the training individuals increase. 5 person is a really small number

Comment: I am facing lighting issues i think.